# Emulate PHP arrays in Python dictionary

Tags: php, python

Converting a PHP-GTK application to Python, I need a dictionary which works as closely as possible as PHP arrays. After search and tries, I subclassed dict in a myDict() Class, and implemented the first important feature which is the ability to have this work :

```
dict1 = myDict()
dict1[foo1][foo2][foo3] = 1
```

This is implemented in the myDict() Class.

```
class myDict(dict) :

    def __missing__(self, arg) :

        self.__setitem__(arg, myDict())
        return self.__getitem__(arg)
```

Now there is a problem. 
In PHP, if I try to get an undefined key, it returns Null (equivalent of None in Python). 
In a standard Python dict, it would return an error.
In my myDict dictionary, unfortunately it returns an empty myDict

```
toto2 = myDict()
x = toto2["a"]["b"]
print x
```

the print shows : {}
The PHP equivalent of this code would return Null and I would need the Python code above returning None as the value of x.

I have not yet found an idea to have it return None. Because if `__missing__` was returning None, then the second line would provoque an error : NoneType is unsubscriptable.

If anyone has an idea to solve this, I would be grateful, there are months that I am looking for a solution to emulate this "magic" of PHP

Comment: How about just changing your code to not rely on these features?

Comment: *"In PHP, if I try to get an undefined key, it returns Null"* ...and it also throws a notice. You do not, never ever just access an undefined index and rely on it "returning `null`". Bad programmer. Bad. I think you should rather get used to how these things are done in Python and not port bad PHP habits over. After all, people are programming in Python without this feature and they get things done apparently.

Comment: Please, please, please don't ever attempt this, inbound googlers.  There be dragons ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we could make `myDict` return `None` when the key is not in
`myDict`. Then consider `toto2["a"]["b"]`.

Python first evaluates `toto2["a"]`. If `"a"` is not in `toto2` then `toto2["a"]` returns None. Next Python would evaluate `None["b"]` and raise a `TypeError`.

So your desired behavior is not possible in Python.